# ios7 UIStatusBar gets under UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I don't use StoryBoard. But my UiviewController is pushed through UInavigationcontroller. But UInaviationbar is hidden. Is there any way to make status bar behave the same ways as iOS6

Comment: navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

Comment: Place that screen here. Go that Users can get the query easily.

Comment: please paste the screen shot

Answer (score 2):

You should call through your navigationController the method `setNavigationBarHidden:NO`.